# Debugging embedded Lua

Tags: c++, debugging, lua

How do you debug lua code embedded in a c++ application?

From what I gather, either I need to buy a special IDE and link in their special lua runtime (ugh). Or I need to build a debug console in to the game engine, using the [lua debug API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.8) calls.

I am leaning toward writing my own debug console, but it seems like a lot of work.  Time that I could better spend polishing the other portions of the game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several tools floating around that can do at least parts of what you want. I have seen references to a VS plugin, there is a SciTE debugger extension in Lua for Windows, and there is the Kepler project's [RemDebug](http://www.keplerproject.org/remdebug/index.html), as well as their [LuaEclipse](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/).

RemDebug may be on the track of what you need, as it was built to allow for debugging CGI scripts written in Lua. It does require access to the LuaSocket module to provide a communications channel between the target script and a controller as well as a couple of other modules.

A bigger issue might be the ability to load arbitrary modules from within whatever sandbox the game engine has put around your scripts. If you have some control over the engine, then that won't be as big an issue.

This isn't currently possible for developers of Adobe Lightroom plugins, for example, because Lightroom does not expose `require` inside the plugin's sandbox.

A surprise to me has been how rarely I have felt a need for a debugger when working with Lua. I've built several small applications in it for various projects and have been surprised at how well a combination of complete stack backtraces and the occasional `print` call works to locate the bugs that `require "strict"` didn't prevent in the first place.

Comment: The RemDebugger is almost exactly what I was looking for.  It should be usable as is, and give me a good base to customize from.

Answer (score 6):

How about [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda)?? there is a video that explains how to use it, and it works pretty darn well for embedded lua source. (i am a happy customer). and it's pretty cheap.

Comment: I use Decoda and am also very happy with it. It links up seamlessly with your project, and requires no setup whatsoever. You can even debug Lua with Decoda, and C++ with another debugger a the same time. My only complaint is that the developers (Unknown Worlds) have a much higher priority project on their hands (Natural Selection 2), so my support requests have gone unanswered. (It turns out my issue wasn't Decoda's fault anyway). Also, the project listing doesn't support a tree view, so once you get a lot of files, it can turn into one long list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my debugger: [GRLD](https://github.com/neuoy/GRLD) (graphical remote lua debugger). Like RemDebug it uses a socket connection, but unlike RemDebug it has a nice graphical interface. The source code is provided, so you can make it work on any platform. It works with the standard lua runtime. Free of charge for non-commercial use.

EDIT: sorry, I had to close the website, so the software is not available for download anymore. I might release it as open source software later, if I ever find the time.

EDIT 2: link updated, now hosted in github under the MIT license (open source)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write your own console as you may want to start with one of the existing ones. RemDebug has already been suggested; I have been developing MobDebug, which is a debugger based on RemDebug, but with a host of new features and bug fixes. The detailed list of the changes is in the [README](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug/blob/master/README).

Enabling debugging in your script may be as simple as adding `require('mobdebug').start()` (if you are running your app and the debugger server on the same machine). This should try to connect to the debugger listening on a default port on localhost. You can use a command-line interface included in MobDebug, or you can use a [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/), which is a Lua IDE that integrates with MobDebug to provide debugging capabilities. The IDE supports debugging for Love2d, Moai, and other Lua engines and may well work for your set up too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how calling DebuggerBreak should work, since that is .NET specific. I would assume that only works with the forked Lua targeting the CLR.

If you are using standard Lua you have some rudementary debugging facilities through the lua function call debug.debug(). That will throw Lua into your console, so if you are running lua from a console, you should be able issue lua commands interactively to inspect your current state. debug.debug() wont put you into the current stack frame, so you have to use debug.getlocal() to read the values of your variables.

I haven't tried it myself yet, but I actually don't think making your own workable debug console is that much work. Remember Lua is not as complicated language as C++, so doing this is a lot easier than making a real C++ debugger like say gdb.

I think there are a lot of people who have done similar things already, whos code you could look at. [Here](http://luaforge.net/projects/clidebugger/) is CLI debugger written in only lua. Just one lua file. Shouldn't be to hard use and modify for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and VS - Can you use the trick we use?

Copy the lua code in a file. Then in the lua code make a call to the Debugger api (in C++ this is `DebuggerBreak()` I think - see [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx)). then when the lua code executes the debugger will fire up and you should be able to specify the file. Then debug as normal?

Comment: That solves half the problem.  What I'd really like to do is execute the lua code line by line.  If in understand your solution, I'll be able to break at any line in the lua script, but I'll be in the c++ debugger.  How would I inspect local lua variables and such.

Comment: I see this as a problem in two parts - one is easy inspection which would be hard as you'd be writing debugger extensions to do this. The second way would be determine how the the lua 'engine' stores these values and inspect them either manually or via macro's perhaps.